# NSURLRequest setting the HTTP header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I need to set the HTTP header for a request. In the documentation for the NSURLRequest class I didn't find anything regarding the HTTP header. How can I set the HTTP header to contain custom data?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You need to use a [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest)

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                autorelease];

[request setValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Field You Want To Set"];
```

or to add a header:

```
[request addValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Field You Want To Set"];
```

Comment: Is there any API for adding dictionary of headers ?

Answer (score 11):

for Swift

```
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: APIBaseURL + "&login=1951&pass=1234")!
var params = ["login":"1951", "pass":"1234"]
request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Comment: I'm using similar kind of code to make a request, but it's returning **nil** data. I tried to what's wrong and only thing i could come up was the response value coming back has different value for "Content-Type" as opposed to what i'm trying to append in the beginning of code. `request.setValue("Some value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` is this working for you?

Comment: try this header   request.addValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Comment: I tried that as well, but it did not work. Finally using myParameters.dataUsingEncoding worked for me, i was using something else that's the reason i think it wasn't working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"your value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"for key"];//change this according to your need.
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: You should probably add some explanation for the code you have posted.

Comment: What does setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" mean, is it sth custom?

Comment: In the case of limited support for POST in the HTTP client software where pure data cannot be submitted in the HTTP message body, RESTfm is able to handle data encoded in either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data formats.

Note: The application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data formats are only applicable to the HTTP POST method

Note 2:  This format uses the same 'URL encoding' scheme as required for GET query string parameters as described here.
Advantages    Support for larger data size than what is possible using a GET query string.

Comment: Refer this link for more detail       http://www.restfm.com/restfm-manual/web-api-reference-documentation/submitting-data/applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and

Answer (score 2):

> I know its late but may help others , For SWIFT 3.0

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.yourwebsite.com")
    let mutAbleRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    mutAbleRequest.setValue("YOUR_HEADER_VALUE", forHTTPHeaderField:"YOUR_HEADER_NAME")
    myWebView.loadRequest(mutAbleRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add value in `NSMutableURLRequest` for HeaderField :

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"cookie"];
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

***Sample Code***

```
 - (void)reqUserBalance:(NSString*)reward_scheme_id id:(NSString*)user_id success:(void (^)(id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(id responseObject))failure{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@reward/%@/user/%@/balance",URL_SERVER,reward_scheme_id,user_id]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Bypass"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
                         options:kNilOptions error:NULL];

         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary * userPoints = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];

             NSString * points = [[userPoints objectForKey:@"points"] stringValue];
             NSLog(@"%@",points);
             [SecuritySetting sharedInstance].usearAvailablePoints = points;


         }
     }];

}
```