# How to access a Web Dynpro page using NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webdynpro

I'm trying to access a SAP Web Dynpro page with in an App. I am using a simple NSURLRequest that works with many other pages. However SAP Web Dynpro is returning the following message

> This Browser is not Supported

Same SAP Web Dynpro link works fine from Safari.

Does anyone have experience dealing with SAP Web Dynpro pages inside an App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a supported browser identification string, otherwise the Web Dynpro renderer won't know what "flavor" to provide and bail out with the error message you quoted. For setting the additional header fields, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809047/nsurlrequest-setting-the-http-header) might help you on....

Comment: Perfect! I found the solution in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk). I added an initialize method in the AppDelegate.m and voila!!! the WebDynpro pages are up and running