# How to change iOS Http Header forKey Connection

Tags: ios, header, connection, nsurlconnection

I use:

```
[header setValue:@"Close" forKey:@"Connection"];
```

to change the `headerField`, but it's not working. The header always in `Connection:keep-alive`, how can I change it?

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809047/nsurlrequest-setting-the-http-header

Comment: [request setValue:@"Close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"]; can,t change the "Connection" field

Comment: The Connection header is normally set automatically by the URL Loading System.  The documentation says not to modify it, and there's no guarantee that changing it in a mutable URL request will have any effect.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Try issuing the requests in separate session each time.  Every session IIRC has a separate connection pool.